# extend groovy.sql.Sql grails 2.4.3

Tags: sql, grails, groovy

I'm creating a plugin and want to use plenty of the grails.sql.Sql methods, so I questioning myself if there is a way to extend it and let grails controller know to use all of it methods (letting me override or add functionality to the ones I need).

My code right know is this:

```
import groovy.sql.Sql

class OdbcController extends Sql {
    def dataSource

    OdbcController(){
        super()
    }
```

the `def dataSource` line is needed for other purpose

could anyone tell me if with this I can call all groovy.sql.Sql implemented methods using this controller?

Thanks in advice

Comment: You might be better with a trait. Though have you met a specific issue? If so, maybe you could explain your problem?

Comment: The problems i'm getting after a few tries are:  datasource is not found as a valid definition (what it does is just inject it but, don't know why it crashes at compile time)

Comment: Why do you want to extend SQL?

Comment: I´m creating a plugin that implements the conection to MonetDB from a jar (loading it driver). At this point I have managed to create some test methods that  use the driver with Grails Sql, but I want to extend Sql  just to change the connection to this new database, so all Sql class methods will work with my Monet database. Finally I want to use this plugin from other applications to connect and interact with MonetDB. Maybe I´m taking the wrong way at trying to extend Sql ,but from now it seems a possible way for me. Any advice or opinion will be welcome

Comment: Just include `Sql` in your class (composition), and pass the `Sql` instance a valid datasource...  Won't that work?

Comment: I'm importing Sql in the class and passing it a valid datasource, but the reason I want to extend Sql class is I don't want to rewrite all Sql methods within my class. I want them to be inherited but using my datasource.     I tried to just extend it but passing the datasource at constructor doesn't work

Comment: Use `@Delegate`?  http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/lang/Delegate.html